# Android - How to update MediaSession Metadata so song changes are reflected on bluetooth connected device?

Tags: android, kotlin, metadata, mediasession

I am using this to set metadata once the player is started. That works great.

```
mediaSession.setMetadata(
                MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                    .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, Variables.currentArtist)
                    .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, Variables.currentSong)
                    .build()
            )
```

When the stream starts playing, the track information is shown on the screen of the bluetooth device connected whether it's an Echo Show or my car's infotainment system. But, once the next song plays, it does not update. I have to stop/start the stream for it to update. How can I push updates to metadata without having to stop/start the playback? I am using this call with a handler every 5 seconds:

```
updateMetadata()
```

Which calls this function:

```
private fun updateMetadata() {
    val largeIcon =
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, com.rustfm.rustfm.R.drawable.album_art)
    mediaSession.setMetadata(
        MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, Variables.currentArtist)
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, Variables.currentSong)
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_DESCRIPTION, "Test Description")
            .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, largeIcon)
            .build()
    )
}
```

Every time I call that updateMetadata() function, my callback class is fired but I am not sure where to go from here. Any help or guidance is appreciated!

This is my call back class:

```
private inner class MediaControllerCallback : MediaControllerCompat.Callback() {

    override fun onMetadataChanged(metadata: MediaMetadataCompat?) {

        // Where to go from here?
        Log.d("Event Metadata", "Fired")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if anyone reads this that has the same problem, my ENTIRE issue was that I wasn't setting the playback state at all in the code. Whoops. The moment I assigned a PlaybackStateCompat to my MediaSession, metadata started displaying and updating properly. I somehow totally forgot to set that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully into this topic, but maybe i can give you some pointers in the right direction. As far as I remember, other services connecting to your media session, receive the information via a `MediaSessionConnector`.

```
/**
 * Creating a media session allows other parties to control the
 * playing radio. For example, the lock screen can now display
 * the net radio status and pause/resume it.
 */
private fun createMediaSession() {
    mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(this, MEDIA_SESSION_TAG)
    mediaSession.isActive = true

    playerNotificationManager.setMediaSessionToken(mediaSession.sessionToken)

    mediaSessionConnector = MediaSessionConnector(mediaSession)
    mediaSessionConnector.setQueueNavigator(object : TimelineQueueNavigator(mediaSession) {
        override fun getMediaDescription(player: Player, windowIndex: Int): MediaDescriptionCompat {
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.bg_radio_notification)
            return MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder()
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.net_radio_channel_name))
                .setSubtitle(notificationSubtitle)
                .setDescription(getString(R.string.radio_channel_description))
                .setExtras(bundleOf(METADATA_KEY_ARTIST to notificationSubtitle)) // for Samsung lock screen
                .setIconBitmap(bitmap)
                .build()
        }

    })

    mediaSessionConnector.setPlayer(player)
}
```

If that is not what you were searching for, I can always recommend to take a good look at the reference implementation of an universal audio player by Google: https://github.com/android/uamp

Also it is very recommendable to use exoplayer as your Player instead of implementing the whole thing yourself. Exoplayer will take off a heavy load of implementation details for you.